# What are good techniques for coping with the loss of a dog?

Tags: dogs, death

There is a unique connection between dogs and their owners. But eventually, this connection must be broken. What are some techniques for coping with losing a beloved friend (dog)? Is it a good idea to buy another dog to comfort you?

Comment: ***Moderator Note*** *Comments under this question have been removed due to extended discussion. A [meta post about the topic of this question](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-questions-about-pet-loss-death-grieving-on-topic) exists to discuss this topic. Please add to the discussion there, thanks!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Early 2009, I lost my dog that was very close to me, we didn't know what killed her but we just found her dead by the road. It was very difficult for me to get over because I loved her so much. I never used any special techniques. It just passed away with time.

Some things you can do to speed up your recovery from a pet loss

- Place a memorial plaque or sign of your dog at a favorite spot of your dog. That way you can pay respect to your dog when you are depressed.
- Try to distract yourself with your fun and favorite activities like exercise, going out with friends, etc.
- After a little mourning for your dog, you could purchase a new dog and engage in all those activities you used to do with your deceased pet like going for a walk in the park, playing fetch, etc. (If your dog has puppies then that's better, you can take console in the puppies, that's one of the thing I did).
- Surround your self with friends who know how close your dog was to you and understand your loss. They'll help in your recovery

Also know that in life there will always be lapses but life goes on and your grief will pass with time. The amount of time that it will take for grief to pass depends on how close your dog was to you, how he died and his age.